# Как передать модульные стили через props'ы? React

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

Есть компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './SectionsTitle.module.css';

const SectionsTitle = (props) => {        
    return <div className={props.styleTitle}>    
        {props.whiteFraction}<span{props.redFraction}</span>
    </div>
}
export default SectionsTitle;
```

Я передаю `styleTitle` через props'ы с родительской компоненты:

```
<SectionsTitle styleTitle='s.SectionsTitle' />
```

Можно ли как-то передать этот `s.SectionsTitle` через props'ы?

Если я делаю таким образом то у меня не получается

Comment: Так с какой другой стороны вы зашли?)) можно эту другую сторону узнать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общая идея такая:

```
// компонент родитель
import React from "react"
import Child from "./path/to/Child"
import styles from "./Parent.module.css"

const Parent = () => {
  // --- правка по комментарию автора ---
  // console.log(styles.myClass)      
  // что бы убедиться что класс существует      
  return <Child myClass={styles.myClass} />
}

export default Parent

// компонент ребенок
import React from "react"

const Child = props => {
  return <div className={props.myClass}>I\'am the child component</div>
}

export default Child
```

Comment: И так пробовал, не получается. В props-ах в дочернюю компоненту приходит 'undefined'.

Comment: @viktor-gif `undefined` скорее всего потому что такого стиля нет, поставьте `console.log(styles.myClass)` в родительском компоненте и проверьте что он выдаст

Comment: Спасибо большое! Доберусь до компьютера - попробую, но стили там есть. В сотый раз проверю. И когда в дочернюю компоненту напрямую передаю {styles.myClass}, все стили работают отлично, а мне стили нужны разные, пришедшие через props-ы. Пока не знаю, где я туплю

Comment: Спасибо! зашел с другой стороны и всё получилось